# How to check the following sets partition another set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Suppose I have a sample space $S$.

I would like to check that the events $A^{c} \cap B \cap C$ and $(A^{c} \cap B \cap C)^{c}$ partition $S$, i.e. that:

1.$(A^{c} \cap B \cap C) \cap (A^{c} \cap B \cap C)^{c} = \emptyset$,

2. $(A^{c} \cap B \cap C) \cup (A^{c} \cap B \cap C)^{c} = S$

I have no idea how to do this , what laws of sets would  be useful here - please help.

Comment: You can more generally prove that, for any $T \subseteq S$, that $T$ and $T^c$ are a partition of $S$.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you @EeveeTrainer